# Клиент-сервер и прокси-сервер

Tags: html, jsp, proxy

Добрый вечер!
У меня работает клиент и сервер, один на *html*, другой - *jsp*, встречаю такую директиву хидера ответа:

```
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
```

читаю описание и не понимаю, как мне прокси-сервер может навредить?

PS [код jsp](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/jsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache-Control - это заголовок для кеширования.

Браузер может закешировать страничку, и вместо запроса к серверу забирать страничку из кеша. В результате на страничке старые данные.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

Заголовок запрещает кешировать страницы *браузеру*.

HTTP прокси сервер может порезать заголовки HTTP запроса, и браузер получив страничку без заголовка (*Cache-Control*) может её закешировать (и снова на странице старые данные), поэтому часто (для критичных данных) добавляют к url специальный параметр с рендомным значением (отпечаток пальца *fingerprint*) вот это прокси точно не порежет.

Перестаньте всё писать на jsp, это вредит последующей поддержке.

Comment: а почему прокси имеет право резать заголовки запросов? Видимо в случаях, когда сообщение слишком длинное? Насколько я понимаю, такая ситуация возможна только в случае *GET* запроса, где длина *url* просто физически ограничена.

Comment: Да, это наиболее очевидная причина, когда на proxy стоит ограничение на размер заголовка, но скорее всего не единственная.